# Need a better way to mass modifying css Class

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a huge collection of list elements.
the concept is that the user can select only two items from that collection.
I am showing a check/Uncheck as an image infront of the list item, just for visual purposes that the list is selected or not.
The image is defined in a class, so I have to switch classes to show selected or unselected.

This is they way I am currently modifying the class but I think it might be too heavy.

```
function showAsSelected(selectedArr, selectedCat) {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("linkRef");
    var len = allLinks.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        allLinks[i].setAttribute('class', 'linkRef subCategLink');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedArr.length; i++) {
        selectedArr[i].setAttribute('class', 'linkRef subCategLinkChkd');
    }
}
```

'allLinks' gets all the elements having class "linkRef". counting above 100 sometimes. The first loop modifies class to 'linkRef subCategLink'. This means it will remove 'subCategLinkChkd' from two elements **(Running a loop on hundreds only to modify two)**.

The second loop sets the class only on the two elements which are referenced in the "selectedArr" array.

Comment: It looks like the first part of the code is to unselected already selected elements. Instead of getting all elements with class `linkRef`, you could get all elements with class `subCategLinkChkd`. I guess that would be fewer. Apart from that, do you have any problems with your code? If not, this question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Well yes, The first part is to unselect. and i tried using subCategLinkChkd but it only references to the elements, so modifying class on the returned collection causes the loop to malfunction

Comment: *"but it only references to the elements"* What does that mean?

Comment: what happens is that I will get a collection of two Elements if I use 'subCategLinkChkd'. Now if I loop through that collection, The loop runs for the first time and changes the class for the first elm, this causes the collection to drop the first elm as it looses reference to 'subCategLinkChkd'. and its length changes from 2 to 1. Thats the reason i am using a static 'linkRef'

Comment: That makes sense. There are two solutions to this problem: (1) Convert the `NodeList` to an array first or (2) iterate over the list in reverse order.

Comment: or maybe use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`, or i missed something ;) and instead of calling setAttribute all the time in loop would be better to use className property?

Comment: Have you tried to add event handler?

Comment: Modified the question with short explanation of the code

Comment: If you add class `subCategLink` to all elements with class `linkRef`, why do not you adding them in markup as default classes?

Comment: @Givi ,  the markup gets generated dynamically. The only issue I have is that I dont want to loop all the hundreds of elements to just change property of two elements

Comment: Did you try [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)? as @FelixKling said you could get all elements with class `subCategLinkChkd` and iterate over them. *querySelectorAll return non live NodeList, it's mean that it's static collection*

Comment: Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/U2Bmy/1) *Updated*

Comment: As I already said in my previous comment, just iterate over the list in reverse order. Or use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Or even better you can try something like this [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/XV7DC/2/) *Updated*

Comment: Givi and Felix Kling , Thank You both !. Both your solutions are neat. Ofcourse I will be using the one which suits my need, But hey, I got to learn three new ways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that you have a similar HTML structure (*and if so*) you can try something like this.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/XV7DC/5/)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var list = document.getElementById("list"),
        selectedInputs = [],
        shifted = null;

    list.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        var target = e.target,
            index = selectedInputs.indexOf(target);
        if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input" &&
            target.type.toLowerCase() === "checkbox" &&
            target.classList.contains("linkRef")) {
            if (target.checked && index === -1) {
                target.setAttribute('class', 'linkRef subCategLinkChkd');
                selectedInputs.push(target);
            } else if (target.checked === false && index !== -1) {
                selectedInputs.splice(index, 1);
                target.setAttribute('class', 'linkRef subCategLink');
            }
            if (selectedInputs.length > 2) {
                shifted = selectedInputs.shift();
                shifted.setAttribute('class', 'linkRef subCategLink');
                shifted.checked = false;
            }
        }
    }, false);
}());
```

***Updated***